# Improve/optimize MySQL code

Tags: php, mysql

Is there any way to optimize this code to run faster and do not execute the same thing twice? (I do have indexes set on users.lat and users.lng)

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM users WHERE users.activated = '1' AND users.id != '1'

AND ROUND((DEGREES(ACOS(SIN(RADIANS('$c_lat')) * SIN(RADIANS(users.lat)) + COS(RADIANS('$c_lat')) * COS(RADIANS(users.lat)) * COS(RADIANS('$c_lng' - users.lng))))) * 60 * 1.1515 * 1.60934 * 1000) >= 1000

AND ROUND((DEGREES(ACOS(SIN(RADIANS('$c_lat')) * SIN(RADIANS(users.lat)) + COS(RADIANS('$c_lat')) * COS(RADIANS(users.lat)) * COS(RADIANS('$c_lng' - users.lng))))) * 60 * 1.1515 * 1.60934 * 1000) <= 5000
```

This code gets the count of all users who are between a distance of 1000 meters and 5000 meters from $c_lat and $c_lng that I pass in PHP.

Also I'd like to avoid using a HAVING clause.

Thanks!

Comment: You should consider MySQL spatial extensions:  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/spatial-extensions.html.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a stored procedure for saving those intermediate values and avoid calculating sins and acos and whatever two times.

You would make the calculations once, store the values in temporary variables and use them to make the query.

Comment: Could you post an example please?

Comment: @eXistenZ You can find a lot of tutorials online on how to do that: http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-stored-procedure-tutorial.aspx